# How would one surmise whether receiver latency is due to misconfigured sender reports or timestamps?

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, rtp

Apologies if this question is a bit general.

Given that SR contain information information used by the receiver to synchronize audio and video, I suspect that the timestamps being sent by a sender are resulting in high playback latency on the receiver.

```
               SR-----------> (high playback latency)
sender (mixer) <------------> receiver
```

This is related to a GStreamer application which acts as a mixer. Therefore it could be related to the timestamps that the mixer (sender) is sending to the receiver.

What are the general steps one would work through to determine if latency is due to a timestamping issue?

Not sure if this is relevant but this only affects some client types.
Different client types paired with the mixer do not have an issue, whereas others always have quite a delay.

I don't believe the latency is network or processing time related.